# Не получается вставить svg элемент из сгенерированного спрайта

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

Я сгенерировала спрайт с иконками svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 17.5 14.663" id="img--svg--icon-twitter" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.283.153c1.736-.485 3.074.263 3.685 1.151.694-.226 1.372-.47 2.072-.691-.004.841-.538 1.478-.883 1.727.704.166 1.343-.48 1.343-.48-.175.976-1.035 1.746-1.611 1.977-.239 6.592-3.272 10.956-10.382 10.823h-.46c-.422 0-4.29-.45-5.047-1.843 2.341.192 4.011-.412 4.835-1.15-.989-.293-2.761-.464-3.07-2.881.362.105.583.223 1.228.117C1.757 8.067.385 7.366.461 5.218c.294.32 1.1.523 1.381.461C1.117 5.444-.188 2.398.921.843 2.794 2.654 4.769 4.364 8.29 4.528 8.506 2.288 9.461.787 11.283.153z"/></symbol>
</svg>
```

Я сохранила его как sprite.svg в папку img. Затем, я хочу вставить его в разметку по id:

```
<ul class="social__list">
      <li class="social__item">
        <a class="social__link social__link--twitter" href="#">
       <svg class="social__link social__link--twitter_icon" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#img--svg--icon-twitter"></use>
       </svg>
      </a></li>
      <li class="social__item"><a class="social__link--facebook" href="#">Фейсбук</a></li>
      <li class="social__item"><a class="social__link--youtube" href="#">Ютуб</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Иконка показывается в firefox, но не показывается в хроме. Версия хрома -  61.0.3163.100. Все расширения хрома я отключала, но все равно не работает.В инвизе тоже. В чем могла бы быть проблема ?
[image: Screen with this svg bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я сохранила его как sprite.svg в папку img.

То есть svg иконки у вас находятся в отдельном файле, поэтому вы его сначала должны добавить в Html страничку

```
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/sprite.svg" >
       Your browser does not support SVG
    </object>
```

О других способах добавления svg в Html [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047#object-p)

Далее можете вызывать иконки из добавленного файла спрайта. Вызывать лучше по id symbol. Это необходимо для кросcбраузерного решения. SVG лучше работает с id, чем с классами.

```
 <li class="social__item">
        <a class="social__link social__link--twitter" href="#">
       <svg  width="16" height="16">
      <use xlink:href="#img--svg--icon-twitter"></use>
       </svg>
      </a>
</li>
```

**Обратите внимание**, что при использовании `<use>` не надо добавлять имя svg файла, так как вы его уже добавили в html через тег `<object>`

Comment: Еще один полезный источник https://svgontheweb.com/ru/

Comment: Хм, спасибо, но если я в начале страницы, допустим, подключаю через object (<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/sprite.svg">
  test
</object>), то у меня возникает ошибка This page contains the following errors:

error on line 78 at column 12: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Comment: Строчек вроде <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> у меня нигде больше нет